# Why did some of my line features in one of the vector layers moved?

Tags: qgis-2

[image: The original codes moved to other features and the information changed][image: Another example of one of the features that got mixed up][image: An example of one of the features that changed]I have a map with line features representing roads. Each road has a code which is linked to a CSV file with information on the road. When I opened the file the other day, I realised the CSV files and map doesn't correlate anymore. It seems the codes and information of the line features in QGIS got mixed up and moved around. Is this possible and what can I do to move it back like it was?

[image: The red is the original codes for the lines on the map and the black is the codes after my line features moved around for some reason.]

Comment: Can you also post a screenshot of the csv file (opened in excel or similar program).

Comment: The CSV file is not the problem. The shapefile's information got mixed up. I have not linked any information from CSV files to the shapefile. I only used the codes of the features (roads) in the shapefile as reference, since the roads do not have names to which I can link the data collected from the fieldwork. I have worked on the CSV independently with the idea that I would link all the information, using the codes, after all the data has been captured

Comment: This sounds like an issue I've had with shapefiles where lines of the attribute table became associated with the wrong features. In my case, the cause was because the shapefile was stored on Dropbox, and there were multiple versions that got jumbled when it synced. The solution was to revert to an older version of the file.

Comment: The shapefile was stored in a different location on my PC as the rest of the shapefiles. So I guess this could have been the case. I guess that means associating all the attributes with the features from scratch

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the data from the CSV are joined to the wrong line it's could be that you use an 'auto-ID' from your line or your CSV to make the join. If that's the case any change (using a processionnaire tool, making a save as, ...) will update the ID and and the relation is broken...

The only solution to prevent this is to create permanent field to link data. 
If you have an older version of your data that still have the right relation you could  create a permanent ''relation'' field before redoing the change that break the link. 
If dont have a back-up you'll have to manually set each relation right again....

If the cause of your problem is not an auto-ID thing provide more info on how your data are related and what you do (if anything) to the data (both CSV and lines) that may have broken the relation

Comment: I haven't joined the CSV files to the shapefiles yet. I am currently working on the CSV files in Excel. I am only using the shapefile to look at the position of the road and then add the data to the code relevant to the position in the Excel File. I will then join the CSV files later. My problem is that all the positions of the codes have now changed and I don't know what caused it. The code that was linked to an asphalt road for example is now positioned on a gravel road. I'm afraid that if I start everything from scratch, that this might happen again.

Comment: Your exact problem is still unclear to me. Did you mean that the code in the line shapefile change ? Could it be just a label placement issue ?

Comment: I added some photos to the original question. (I'm not sure where else to post that). You can see from the original shapefile that the codes and information attached to each feature has been mixed up. The other information linked to each feature was just meant to be updated after I have completed the CSV files. I have however not   linked the CSV files yet. I have been working on them independently from the shapefiles, just using the codes on the shapefile as reference.

Comment: In figure 1 and 2 (also fig.3 and 4) there are differences in the road network (not the same number of road, some road have a different shape, more attribute field...) beside the  code. Either the original shapefile has been edited/modified or you are using a different shapefile. If you are sure that you are using the right file then you should find how and why the edit where made and if the code has been changed.

Comment: I did merge certain features and made slight adjustments to the lines to fit the actual roads better, which is why I cannot use the original shapefile anymore. I have however taken a screenshot of this particular features, since I did not alter this.